# Ошибка NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Как выборочно присвоить операцию из одного метода новому объекту класса? Я добавил в метод lte еще 2 операции возвращающие случайное значение, а так же добавил еще два объекта класса: my_lte_2 и my_lte_3.
Как присвоить объекту my_lte_1 значение value_1, my_lte_2 значение value_2 и третьему соответственно? Возможно ли это выполнить не создавая новые методы?

```
import random
class Speed:
    def lte(self):
        value_1 = random.randint(0,40)
        return value_1
        value_2 = random.randint(0,100)
        return value_2
        value_3 = random.randint(0,250)
        return value_3

my_lte_1 = Speed()
print(my_lte_1.lte())

my_lte_2 = Sensors()
print(my_lte_2.lte())

my_lte_3 = Sensors() 
print(my_lte_3.lte())
```

Comment: Чему должно быть равно передаваемое значение?

Comment: `my_lte = Speed(value)` вы задали значение, с которым инициализируете объект класса?

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы это значение ссылалось на значение self.value, описанное в методе. Как раз именно  random.randint(0,40) я и хочу передать в объект my_lte

Comment: не ясно что вы хотите

Comment: тогда не передавайте это значение при создании экземпляра. и не просите при создании в инит. и патом вызовите метод my_lte.lte() и лучшебы вам почитать основы питона

Comment: @Интик отлично, получилось все!

Comment: @Интик И еще хотел бы узнать, можно ли создав второй объект и добавить еще одну операцию в методе, задать для каждого нового объекта по одной операции? 
import random
class Speed:
    def lte(self):
        value_1 = random.randint(0,40)
         value_2 = random.randint(20,250)
my_lte_1 = Speed()
print(my_lte_1.lte()) Добавляю новый объект my_lte_2 = Speed() и как для него выбрать операцию из lte??
print(my_lte_2.lte())

Comment: под вашим вопросом кнопка править, отредактируйте вопрос и обновите код. в комментариях непонятно.

Comment: @Интик прошу меня извинить, исправил.

Comment: lte 1 у вас экземпляр speed. lte 2 у вас экземпляр sensors, но класса sensors у вас нет.  передать значение можно было как в первом варианте , заменив value на число.   прочитайте хотябы эту статью https://python-scripts.com/python-class

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
class Speed:
    def lte(self, number: int):
        value = 0
        if number == 1:
            value = random.randint(0,40)            
        if number == 2:
            value = random.randint(0,100)
        if number == 3:
            value = random.randint(0,250)

        self.value = value

my_lte_1 = Speed()
my_lte_2.lte(2)
print(my_lte_1.value)

my_lte_2 = Sensors()
my_lte_2.lte(2)
print(my_lte_2.value)

my_lte_3 = Sensors() 
my_lte_3.lte(3)
print(my_lte_3.value)
```

Comment: Скажите, почему присваиваем value 0 значение?

Comment: @Danqqq ну можете не инициализировать, а просто написать value: int